# How to make Micronaut find controller interfaces in an external source set

Tags: java, kotlin, jax-rs, micronaut, openapi-generator

I have a micronaut app where I am trying to make use of [openapi-generator](https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator) to generate stub of my controllers. This project doesn't directly support micronaut but it does support jax-rs API definitions [which there is micronaut support for](https://micronaut-projects.github.io/micronaut-jaxrs/latest/guide/index.html), so I'm trying to use those.

openapi-generator generates code into `/generated/src/gen/java`

TestAPI.java:

```
package com.owennewburn.generated.api;


import javax.ws.rs.*;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;

import io.swagger.annotations.*;

import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.List;
import javax.validation.constraints.*;
import javax.validation.Valid;

@Path("/test")
@Api(description = "the test API")
public interface TestApi {

    @GET
    @Produces({ "text/plain" })
    @ApiOperation(value = "Test \"Hello World\" endpoint", notes = "", tags={ "test" })
    @ApiResponses(value = { 
        @ApiResponse(code = 200, message = "success", response = String.class) })
    String helloWorld();
}
```

I have a basic application in the standard `/src/main/kotlin` directory where I'm trying use this interface.

Application.kt:

```
package com.owennewburn.myapp

import io.micronaut.runtime.Micronaut

class Application: javax.ws.rs.core.Application() {

    fun main(args: Array<String>) {
        Micronaut.build()
            .packages("com.owennewburn.")
            .classes(TestController::class.java)
            .mainClass(this.javaClass)
            .start()
    }
}
```

TestController.kt

```
package com.owennewburn.myapp

import com.owennewburn.generated.api.TestApi

class TestController: TestApi {

    override fun helloWorld(): String {
        return "Hello World"
    }
}
```

I then have a simple test that tries to do `GET /test` and checks the response.

In this state the test will fail **but if I move the interface into the src directory with the rest of the application code it works**. Any ideas why this would be? In both cases the code builds and runs, but only when the interface is in the main project directory does the endpoint get created when the code is run.

Answer (score 0):

In the end this is a build problem. In my build.gradle file sourceSets looked like:

```
sourceSets {
    main {
        kotlin {
            srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
            srcDirs += files("${openApiSourceDir}/src/gen/java")
        }
    }
}
```

Which was enough to successfully compile the code but would only create compiled versions of the kotlin files not the java interfaces. [Micronaut uses compile time data to implement dependency injection](https://docs.micronaut.io/latest/guide/ioc.html) so by not having the interfaces available on the classpath, they are not found when the package scan is done to inform dependency injection.

I fixed it by changing build.gradle to:

```
sourceSets {
    main {
        kotlin {
            srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
            srcDirs += files("${openApiSourceDir}/src/gen/java")
        }
        java {
            srcDirs += files("${openApiSourceDir}/src/gen/java")
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: "so by not having the interfaces available on the classpath, they are not found when the package scan is done to inform dependency injection" - Which package scanning are you referring to?

Comment: I could be incorrect, I'm fairly new to micronaut so my understanding could be flawed, but when the micronaut application is run I have to specify a set of packages that contain the components that make up the app.

From ApplicationContextBuilder.java
`
    /**
     * The packages to include for package scanning.
     *
     * @param packages The packages
     * @return This builder
     */
    @Nonnull ApplicationContextBuilder packages(@Nullable String... packages);
`

Comment: The interfaces not being on the classpath would cause other runtime problems, but not classpath scanning problems.